# IOS setting Cell height to depend on url image height width ratio

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to display a flowing list of Items. The width of the item image should be the width of the screen and the height should be such that the image is not stretched or shrunk.

Below the item image should be the item's name and the username of the user who owns the item.

I have most of this done. The only issue is that the height of the collectionView card is set (non dynamic). So the image usually either overflows the card or does not fill all the cards height and there is whitespace.

Is the some way to change the height of the card to depend on the height of the image?

Here is my itemCellView called "CollViewCell":

```
import UIKit
import AlamofireImage

class CollViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgCell: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelCell: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelUserNameCell: UILabel!
}
```

Here is the Viewcontroller code that has to do with Collection

```
...
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.viewModel.getItems(self.viewModel.getCurrentUser()) { items in
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

    }
}

...

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: CollViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollViewCell
    cell.labelCell.text = self.viewModel.tableDict[indexPath.row]![0]
    let imageUrl = NSURL(string: self.viewModel.tableDict[indexPath.row]![1])
    cell.imgCell.af_setImageWithURL(imageUrl!, placeholderImage: nil, filter: nil, imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.2))
    cell.labelUserNameCell.text = self.viewModel.tableDict[indexPath.row]![2]

    return cell
}
...
```

The ViewMode on the storyboard is set to Aspect Fill and the Semantic is left to right

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're able to calculate the image height, you can try using a combination of `estimatedItemSize` of a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and its delegate function `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`.

Tell your collection view to use a flow layout and return an average cell size for the `estimatedItemSize`.  Then, in `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` you'll use the calculated image size to determine the actual size for your collection view item.  The `UIImageView` inside should be taking advantage of autolayout to fill in the increased size.